# delete first line and 3 columns from txt file

Tags: linux, awk, sed, hidden, cut

I have a file in the following format:

```
Received 4 packets, got 4 answers, remaining 252 packets
52:54:00:12:35:00 192.168.1.1
52:54:00:12:35:00 192.168.1.2
08:00:27:87:d3:08 192.168.1.3
08:00:27:3e:99:5c 192.168.1.23
```

I want to delete first line and the mac col from all the lines , The output should be:

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.23
```

and the command run in background please I don't need to show result in terminal window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'NR != 1 {print $2}' file1
```

In action

```
$ cat file1
Received 4 packets, got 4 answers, remaining 252 packets
52:54:00:12:35:00 192.168.1.1
52:54:00:12:35:00 192.168.1.2
08:00:27:87:d3:08 192.168.1.3
08:00:27:3e:99:5c 192.168.1.23
$ awk 'NR != 1 {print $2}' file1
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.23
```

---

For silent output, you could direct the output to another file.

```
$ awk 'NR != 1 {print $2}' file1 > file2
$ cat file2
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.23
```

Comment: i got the output like this : root@kali:/media/sf_Desktop# awk 'NR != 1 {print $2}' textout.txt > qassam.txt
root@kali:/media/sf_Desktop# cat qassam.txt 
4
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.23
 ... i dont need (4)

Comment: Interesting. What is your awk version ? I get this `GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.5, GNU MP 6.1.1)` from `awk --version` @evilcode1

Comment: Also can you try with `awk 'FNR != 1 {print $2}' textout.txt` Made the NR into FNR @evilcode1

Comment: it;s awk GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.6, GNU MP 6.1.2) and i still got (4) also when i execute this awk 'FNR != 1 {print $2}' textout.txt

Comment: What are the first two lines of your textout.txt ? @evilcode1

Comment: (space)
Received 4 packets, got 4 answers, remaining 252 packets
(space)52:54:00:12:35:00 192.168.1.1

Comment: :) I think you have an empty line in the first line of your textout.txt file. @evilcode1

Comment: Can you try with this `awk 'NR > 2 {print $2}' textout.txt` if you want to keep the first empty line. @evilcode1

Comment: You could: `sed '2,$s/.* //p;d'` ! Shorter and simplier: *From line 2 to end of input: Drop everything from left to the last space*.